# How to generate log history containing a certain keyword?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoise-svn

For the purpose of documentation I want to get an SVN log history of commits which have a message containing a certain keyword.

When I do it manually I open Tortoise SVN, search for a keyword like [REVIEW], use Ctrl+A to highlight all search results and copy it to the clipboard. When pasting this into a notepad or Word I have a nice overview of all commits, its author, date, message and which files have been added, removed or modified.

I would like to find all messages containing the keyword `[REVIEW]`.

Unfortunately none of these work:

```
svn log --search "[REVIEW]" -v

svn log --search "REVIEW" -v

svn log --search ?REVIEW? -v
```

The second example shows nearly every commit ever made on the repository...

Does anyone how to search for `[REVIEW]` in the messages of an SVN log using the Windows command line?

Comment: Does [Searching subversion history (full text)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/44176) help?

Comment: This was one of the links I searched in the last hours. However, the solution was much simpler. The problem was the use of [ and ] in the log message.

Comment: So you have a solution? If so you should post an answer to your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I'm familiar with the SE network and was already writing my answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was quite simple.

This combination did the trick:

```
svn log --search "?REVIEW?" -v
```

The use of `[` and `]` in the SVN log message caused my search patterns to fail or to result in too many found entries.

Since `--search` supports regex-like wildcards [review] returned all commits containing r, e, v, i or w.
Wildcard `?` can be used to search for one occurrence of any character.

However, I don't know why `"?REVIEW?"` worked `?REVIEW?` didn't.

Comment: Probably the ? was interpreted by your shell when you didn't quote it. Similar to problems caused trying to set properties to `*` without quoting it.